# Bash linux increment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting

i am trying to increment a variable name inside a for loop to get 4 dynamic variable in each loop, this is an example

```
while read line
do
        for n in `seq 1 4`
                do
                vr$n=$(echo -e "$line" | awk '{print $'$n'}')
                #test
                echo vr$n
        done
done < rst.txt

cat rst.txt 
AAA BBB CCC DDD
111 222 333 444
*** --- /// +++
```

my problem is that when i try to execute the script it try to execute the result in the variable and i get an error 'command not found'
any idea plz?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming a variable with a variable (`vr$n=value`) is not possible without an `export`. However, I suggest to use an array instead:

```
vr[$n]=$(echo -e "$line" | awk '{print $'$n'}')
```

and reference the value afterwards with a syntax like this:

```
echo ${vr[$n]}
```

Comment: it worked thanks, just a small question, i think name of this vars will be vr[n] (vr[1], vr[2], vr[3] ...), if i plan to use this vars after on the same script file so no need to export it i need just to call the var with his name exp : echo vr[1] and to run the script need i to source it (source ./my_script.sh) thanks again for your help

Comment: as i returned after more then 5 min i cannot edit my comment. tested and working as expected, no need to source the script.